# Помогите с board в VkApi

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Делаю вывод в `ListView` обсуждения с группы:

```
VKParameters param = new VKParameters();
param.put(VKApiConst.GROUP_ID, группа);
VKRequest result = new VKRequest(String.format(Locale.US, "%s.%s", "board", "getTopics"),
    param, VKRequest.HttpMethod.GET, VKApiTopicArray.class);
result.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);
        topics = (VKApiTopicArray)response.parsedModel;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (VKApiTopic topic : topics) {
            sb.append(topic.title);
            sb.append("\r\n\r\n");
        }
        arr_list.add(sb.toString());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
```

Все обсуждения приходят верно! Но вот вопрос, как реализовать метод входа в нужную тему обсуждения? Тоже же надо какой-то `VKRequest` делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В официальной документации VK API описан [метод получения сообщений](https://vk.com/dev/board.getComments) из топика. Реквест делайте по аналогии.

```
    VKParameters param = new VKParameters();
    param.put(VKApiConst.GROUP_ID, "ID_ГРУППЫ");
    param.put("topic_id", "ID_ТОПИКА");
    VKRequest result = new VKRequest(String.format(Locale.US, "%s.%s", "board", "getComments"),
            param, VKCommentArray.class);
    result.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            VKCommentArray parsedModel = (VKCommentArray)response.parsedModel;
            for (VKApiComment topic : parsedModel) {
                System.out.println(topic.text);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Вопрос как сделать по анологии??

Comment: кладете в VKParameters param id группы и топика, делаете запрос, парсите ответ. Аналогично коду, который вы прикрепили к вашему вопросу.

Comment: param.put(VKApiConst.GROUP_ID, группа); как сюда положить ID топика???

Comment: param.put("topic_id", "ид топика");

Comment: По дебаггеру только size=1 (это типа один топик? Ибо в моем топике ~70 комментартев)...что надо использовать для получения комментариев определенного топика обсуждения?

Comment: в документации в примере запроса можно увидеть: там должен вернуться объект респонс, у которого есть список "items", это и есть сообщения.

Comment: Как его вызвать, этот items??? мне кажется я уже перепробывал все((((....помогите новичку....

Comment: поправил ответ. попробуйте, отпишитесь

Comment: Да работает...Спасибо огромное! А как человека отобразить  писавшего коммент(имя и фото)?????

Comment: Помогите еще распарсить PROFILE комментируемого?